# How to remove the black color background in a video cause by the transparent canvas area in a video?

Tags: video, html5-canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqdkB.png)

I have trouble removing the black color behind the phone video it causes by the transparent canvas.

Comment: What is your expected result? You want a blurred background (blurred second copy of video as black area)? Or you want to stretch the video to fit the sides (may look squashed)?

Comment: I just want it to remove the black by using code. But I solve it yesterday using photoshop having transparent background will become black on web page so I used white instead. I hope there's a code to do it.